# Load CSV's by Matching names and fetch specific Cols by maching Tag Names

Tags: r, csv

I have two data frames having "TagNames" and "FileNames" and I have CSV files in a directory. I need to open csv files one by one using "FileNames" then fetch columns from CSV file by matching "TagNames", append them to a "result" data frame and move to next CSV file (repeat). 
Note: I also have to take care of date and time because records coming from different files must be place according to date and time.

TagNames and File Names are as follows: [Tag Names and File Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUyJ.png)

Files Directory and Data Looks Like This: [Files Directory and Data Shape in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ57W.png)

My R Script is this:

```
basepath <- dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)
# Load the Data
basepath <- dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)
FilesDF <- read.csv("Config/Files.csv")
TagsDF <- read.csv("Config/Tags.csv")

FilesList <- list(FilesDF)
TagsList <- list(TagsDF)

extractData <- function(x) {
result <- NULL;
temp <- NULL;
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
new_df <- read.csv(file=x$FileNames[i,], header=TRUE, sep=",")
for(j in q:ncol(new_df))
{
  temp <- rbind(temp, new_df[which(new_df[1,j])==TagsList$Tag.Names[i,]])
}
result <- rbind(result, temp)
temp <- NULL
}
return(result)
}
df_combined <- lapply(FilesList, extractData)
write.csv(df_combined, file = "UreaSVR2.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R would use something like:

`rbind(lapply(lapply(fileList, read.csv), subset, select = TagsList))`

The inner `lapply()` reads in all of the files in the list, the outer one `subset`s the data and uses the `select` argument which takes in a vector of column names. Finally, `rbind` puts the list together into a single `data.frame`.

I would probably using `purrr` and `dplyr` myself though I write it more like this:

`map(fileList, read.csv) %>%
map_df(select, TagNames)`

Comment: getting following error when I use map(): Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: What's the class of fileList? What's the output of lapply(fileList, class)? Note.

Comment: For map() to work you probably don't want to make it a list() from a data.frame since I think you'll get a one element list with your column. Instead you want FilesDF$FileNames.

Comment: I have tried both and encountered same error. Yes you are right, List have only one element. I have used the first solution (lapply) as well. There must be some solution @JBecker..?

Comment: I'll spend some time later today creating a small example locally to figure out how to correct it up.

Comment: > files$files
[1] "funds.csv"                  "locations.csv"
[3] "objects.csv"                "project_resource_codes.csv"
[5] "purposes.csv"               "use_1.csv"
[7] "use_2.csv"
> map(files$files, read.csv, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% map_df(subset, select = c('V1', 'V2')) worked for me, which is basically what I have above. You may want to do map(fileList$FileNames, print) or similar to make sure you're passing in what you think.